# Enumeration using blocks and variables iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

I have a a block for enumeration and some properties in an .h file and want to access them inside my block how can i do that?

here is my code:

```
.h file

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *productsArray;

.m file


NSArray *products = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"products"];
        [products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
            //getting the products links on productsArray
            [self.productsArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"thumbnail_url"]];
        }];
```

but my _productsArray is empty after the block execution

i've studied about _block variable name but what about properties?

i just want to get an array after the enumeration with some particular items!

Is that a good practice?

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initalise the productsArray at some point before adding objects to it:

```
self.productsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: OHHHH yeah silly question i guess! Sorry about that and thanks a lot man!